# HTML TR and TD alignment

Tags: vbscript, html-table

[image]

This is what I've done, but I failed to make the alignment same as next picture. Hope someone can help.

```
<tr>
    <td >&nbsp;</td>
    <td ><b>Type Description</b></td>
    <td align="Center"><b>:</b></td>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="txtCAEMGE" value="<%=server.HTMLEncode(StrCAEMDE)%>" type="text" class="NormalInputTextField" size="30" >
    &nbsp;<input name="chkHR" type="checkbox"> Tick for disable update from HR system
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td >&nbsp;</td>
    <td >&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;
    <input name="chkHR2" type="checkbox"> Tick for disable update from HR system
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Try giving style="display: block" to the second 'td' which you want to bring down.

Comment: You could show the code of your result (according to the image below)

Comment: @JinuKurian hi..can you show me with my original code..i tried but not work..

Comment: @Jan please provide the css

Comment: @JinuKurian i'm writing that in vbscript..the code r provided on top..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would experiment with putting both checkboxes inside a single container (e.g. a DIV). If you want to position them as a single entity then it will be easier if they are organised in the DOM this way.

e.g.

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Type Description</b></td>
            <td align="Center"><b>:</b></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="test value" size="30" >&nbsp;
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <div style="display: block;"><input name="chkHR" type="checkbox"> Tick for disable update from HR system</div>
                    <div style="display: block;"><input name="chkHR2" type="checkbox"> Tick for disable update from HR system</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: hi..thanks for reply..can you show me with my original code..i tried but not work..

Comment: I think that you'll need "display: inline-block" on the container I mentioned (https://jsfiddle.net/2jehk7he/).